# PHPUnit to log test case result in Database

Tags: php, phpunit, tdd

I have a test method i want to log the test result in database. what is the best way to do this?

The field i want to log is

1. Method Name
2. Test Result

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a PHPUnit test listener. See [Implement PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.examples.SimpleTestListener.php).

There are also some existing plugins to look at for usage. See [Plugins for PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/plugins.html).

### Example

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SimpleTestListener implements PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener
{
    public function addError(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {
        printf("Error while running test '%s'.\n", $test->getName());
    }

    public function addFailure(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e, $time)
    {
        printf("Test '%s' failed.\n", $test->getName());
    }

    public function addIncompleteTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {
        printf("Test '%s' is incomplete.\n", $test->getName());
    }

    public function addRiskyTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {
        printf("Test '%s' is deemed risky.\n", $test->getName());
    }

    public function addSkippedTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {
        printf("Test '%s' has been skipped.\n", $test->getName());
    }

    public function startTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test)
    {
        printf("Test '%s' started.\n", $test->getName());
    }

    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time)
    {
        printf("Test '%s' ended.\n", $test->getName());
    }

    public function startTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
    {
        printf("TestSuite '%s' started.\n", $suite->getName());
    }

    public function endTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
    {
        printf("TestSuite '%s' ended.\n", $suite->getName());
    }
}
```

> The `<listeners>` element and its `<listener>` children can be used to attach additional test listeners to the test execution.
>
> — [The XML Configuration File — Test Listener](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.test-listeners).

```
<listeners>
  <listener class="MyListener" file="/optional/path/to/MyListener.php">
    <arguments>
      <array>
        <element key="0">
          <string>Sebastian</string>
        </element>
      </array>
      <integer>22</integer>
      <string>April</string>
      <double>19.78</double>
      <null/>
      <object class="stdClass"/>
    </arguments>
  </listener>
```

Comment: i want to log test result in database.i am using laravel  when test fail  i added my logic in addFailure method but can u tell me how i add my records in database there..Any Idea?

Comment: How to add records to a database using Laravel is too broad. Perhaps try the [SO Laravel Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/1093/database#t=201609282205410940315).